# How to measure the number of times an ad is seen?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-ads-api, ads, impressions

What i want to ask, you can understand with this example.

This site *www.cashbackforex.com* provides a banner like this

```
<a href="https://www.cashbackforex.com/#aid_18248#bid_1"><img src="https://www.cashbackforex.com/referrals/referrals.bannerimage?aid=18248&bid=1"></a>
```

As you can see there is no other script only to show an image with a link on it.

But when i display this banner [only display without any click] on any other site, its impression count increases by 1 on *casbackforex.com*.

This is what i want to do to my site. I have searched google many times, questions asked everywhere but i didn't find anyway to proceed.

Please provide any clue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Image is referenced by an URL that points to a server side script:

```
<img src="[...]/referrals/referrals.bannerimage?[...]" />
```

My guess would be that this script takes the Parameter and increments the corresponding counter. Then it directlz returns the image, instead of text. It doesn't really count how often it has been seen, it counts how often the image is requested.

Comment: yes you might be right, i didn't notice this before. anyway this gives me an idea to do that using a script with that. thanks